# measure of the boundary of the support

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb R^d$. Does the boundary of the support of $\mu$ have measure zero, i.e. do we have
$$\mu(\partial(\text{supp}\mu))=0,$$ where we define the support of $\mu$ as the smallest closed set such that its complement has $\mu$-measure zero?

Answer (score 3):

No; for instance, consider the case that $\mu$ is a point mass.

Comment: ok so the boundary of a point is the point itself